# Showing that Closure of a Ball is Not the Closed Ball

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $\overline{B_d (x, r)}$ be the closure of a ball in some metric space ($X, d$), and let $\hat{B}_d (x, r)$ be the closed ball in some metric space ($X, d$). Prove, or disprove, that $\overline{B_d (x, r)}$ = $\hat{B}_d (x, r)$ in any metric space.

I have a sense the answer is false when we use the discrete metric (professor told us if we ever want to "break" open/closed relationship, we should start with the discrete metric), but can't really understand how it would be false.

I was thinking maybe considering some radius $r > 1$. Then, $\overline{B_d (x, r)}$ would be just $x$ itself (i.e. {$x$}), since we can't have a radius greater than $1$ with the discrete metric, right? But then wouldn't $\hat{B}_d (x, r)$ be the same thing since we can't have distances greater than $1$..? I don't think I'm really understanding the discrete metric well. How would this statement be false wrt. the discrete metric? Any explanation/clarity would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In discrete topology, for $r=1,$ the closure  $$\overline{B_d (x, r)}$$ is the intersection of all closed sets which include $ B_d (x, r)$ and that is the singleton{$x$}.

On the other hand the closed ball, $$ \hat{B}_d (x, r)$$ is the whole space.

Thus the two sets  are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of considering some radius $r>1$, why don't you consider the more blatantly problematic radius $r=1$? As a hint that you are in the right track, you should arrive in a point/whole space situation.

Comment: If $r = 1$, then the closed ball would be all the elements of $X \le 1$, right? In that case, that'd be the the entire space, since radii $\le 1$ includes both $x$ itself and everything else. But wouldn't this be the closure as well, since we're adding all the limit points into the ball as well?

Comment: @Max Your justification is a little strangely written (what are "elements of $X \leq 1$"?), but I think you have the right idea. And yes, the closed ball is the whole space. But you said the closure would be as well, since we are "adding all the limit points". Why do you think that every other point is a limit point?

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{ if }x=y\\
1, & \mbox{ if }x\neq y
\end{cases}.
$$
We can verify that the axioms of metric are satisfied. That is, $d(x,x)=0$,
$d(x,y)=d(y,x)$, and $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Let $X=\mathbb{R}$
as a set, but equipped with metric $d$. Pick any $x_{0}\in X$, then
$B(x_{0},1)=\{x_{0}\}$, $\hat{B}(x_{0},1)=X$. Obviously $B(x_{0},1)$
is closed, so $\overline{B(x_{0},1)}=B(x_{0},1)\neq\hat{B}(x_{0},1)$.